# Bash - Rename file that have " in it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file

Ok I have a *function* that will have as parameter a string and it will output a *new string* that **doesn't** have any **spaces**, `'`, `"`

```
function rename_file() {

local string_to_change=$1
local length=${#string_to_change}
local i=0   
local new_string=" "
local charac

for i in $(seq $length); do
    i=$((i-1))
    charac="${string_to_change:i:1}"

    if [ "$charac" != " " ] && [ "$charac" != "'" ] && [ "$charac" != """ ];  then #Here if the char is not" ", " ' ", or " " ", we will add this char to our current new_string and else, we do nothing

        new_string=$new_string$charac #simply append the "normal" char to new_string

    fi

done

echo $new_string #Just print the new string without spaces and other characters
}
```

But I just can't test if the char is `"` because it just doesn't work. And if I call my function with

```
rename_file (file"n am_e)
```

it just open `>` and waits for me to enter something.. any help ?

Comment: Have you tried rename_file (file\"n am_e)

Comment: If you type (or put in a script) `rename_file(file"n ame)`, then you have not called the function `rename_file` with the argument `file"n ame`.  Rather, you have entered the beginning of a string, and bash is prompting you and waiting for you to terminate the string.  Try `rename_file file\"n ame`

Comment: Not sure if you want a purely bash solution, but may I suggest a one-liner instead? :) `new_string=$(echo $string | sed -e 's/ //' -e 's/,//' -e 's/"//')`. Also, change `$1` to `${@}` as a function parameter, otherwise it will break on spaces.

Comment: Yes Matias it works but the goal is to retrieve a file name from a repository and correct this name. So I will call this function as : rename_file(filename)

Comment: favoretti it doesn't work because the part `'s/,//'` is replacing `,` and if I want to use it to replace `'` it opens the same `> ` and waits for me to input a thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the name in single quotes.

```
rename_file 'file"n am_e'
```

And if you want to test single quotes, put it in double quotes:

```
rename_file "file'n am_e"
```

To test both, put them in double quotes and escape the inner double quotes:

```
rename_file "file'na \"me"
```

Another option is to use a variable:

```
quote='"'
rename_file "file'na ${quote}me"
```

Also, you don't need to put parentheses around the arguments to a shell function. They're called like ordinary commands, with arguments separated by spaces on the same command line.

And you don't need that loop to replace characters.

```
new_string=${string_to_change//[\"\' ]/}
```

See [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the Bash Manual for an explanation of this syntax.

Comment: I suspect the OP does not actually want the parens in the filename, and it may be helpful to point out that they are not needed in a function call.

Comment: Ah, this one is actually quite cool! I forgot about expansions myself, offered a sed-based solution in the comment to OP.

Comment: thanks ! And how can I define a filename like : `fi'le na"me` to test ? Because if I put it like that : `"fi'l'e na"me"` it will consider the 3 `"` and will open `>` and will wait for me to input something    
**and** if I put it like that : `'fi'le na"me'` it will consider the 3 `'` and will open `>` and will wait for me to input something too

Comment: And I can't put `\"` in it because it's a filename so it doesn't have this `\"` in it.

Comment: @RomainB. To provide the string `fi'le na"me` to the shell, you have several options.  `touch "fi'le na\"me"` is probably the easiest.  That will create a file that has `"` in it, and not `\"`.  You are just escaping the `"` to the shell to tell the shell that you do not intend that to be the closing quote.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Exactly what I was looking for.. thanks

Comment: And how could I call this in my function rename_file ? 
I tried `rename_file (touch fi'le_name)` but it doesn't work

Comment: And yeah I just can't call my function with a filename for example : `file"name` because the terminal will open `>`..

Comment: @RomainB. How is that different from your original question, which I answered?

Comment: Because I can't put `\"` inside my filename

Comment: Why can't you do that? The backslash isn't in the actual filename, it's just the way you type it in the shell.

Comment: I just added another method using a variable.